# Google Glass - App not working without USB

Tags: usb, google-glass, google-gdk

I have an issue with my Google Glass. While working with the GDK in Eclipse [Android 4.4.2] AND Google Glass attached to my computer via USB, my application runs smoothly. When disconnected it gets stuck after the initial voice input. This is not the "ok glass" command to start my application but the first voice input after the start of the application. Glass afterwards recognizes the voice input correctly, but fails to display the next screen. Once again: with the USB cable attached it works perfectly.

Anyone out there with an idea where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem.

The issue was, that I still had my Glass looking for the Debugger, what might prove difficult without USB connection. 
So my solution was to comment this:

```
// Include Debugger
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```